# How to test functions in React with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component called Contact which in turn has a child component called Header.I am passing a function into my Header component called **handleButtonClick()** . The function is called in the component like this :

```
<Header  handleButtonClick={this.openPopup} >
```

and the openPopup() function is defined in the Contact component as shown below:

```
openPopup = () => this.setState({ popupOpen: true });
```

So, I am trying to test this function using jest and Enzyme:

```
it("calls the `openPopup` function", () => {
        const onMockFunction = jest.fn();
        const comp = shallow(
            <SparkTheme>
                <Contact handleButtonClick={onMockFunction} />
            </SparkTheme>
        );
        comp.find(Header).simulate("change");
        expect(onMockFunction).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

So, when I run this test I get an error saying:

```
Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.
```

What is the issue?Can anyone please help me with this?

**NOTE:** Also, if I have another function which takes some parameters as shown below,

```
setValue = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
```

then how do i write the test case.Should it be something like:

```
comp.find(Header).simulate("change", event);
```

I am not able to check as its failing. please guide me in this.

**EDIT 1:** After doing comp.debug(), the output I get is:

```
<div>
        <Header contactCount={3} handleButtonClick={[Function: bound ]} buttonText="View all">
          Site Contact From HTML
        </Header>
        <ContactList name="displayContacts" data={{...}} />
        <Popup open={false} onRequestClose={[Function: bound ]}>
          <styled.h3>
            Contacts
          </styled.h3>
          <SearchBar onRequestClear={[Function: bound ]} setValue={[Function: bound ]} value="" />
          <styled.div>
            <ContactList hasLeftPadding={true} popupDisplay={true} data={{...}} />
          </styled.div>
        </Popup>
      </div>
```

And the error message i get now after writing as:

```
comp
            .dive()
            .find(Header)
            .prop("handleButtonClick")({ target: { value: "someValue" } });
```

is:

```
TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components
```

Comment: you said that `handleButtonClick` is defined on Header component, but in the above code snippet(3rd snippet), you have mentioned it on `Contact` component and also you have attached the mock function there. You might need to correct the above code .

Comment: `.simulate` works on DOM events, first you need to find the element which had `onClick` event and then trigger simulate on it. Read more here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that shallow only renders one level deep, so it can't find the `Header`. Just use `console.log(comp.debug())` to see what was rendered.  You could use [`dive`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) to go one level deeper.

Next problem is that `Header` has no `change` event attached but`handleButtonClick`. So to trigger this you need to call on the `prop` like this:

```
comp.find(Header).prop("handleButtonClick")({target: {value: 'someValue'}})
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response.But I am still getting an error. I tried dive() like this `comp
            .find(Header)
            .prop("handleButtonClick")({ target: { value: "someValue" } })
            .dive();` , but now I get the error saying: `Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.` Is it not the correct way. can you please check and guide me.

Comment: Please use comp.debug() to see what was really rendered. Also dive must be called like this `comp.dive().find ...`

Comment: I have written the output of comp.debug() and the error message now in an edit above.Can you please check?

Comment: So and it still dont find the `Header`?

Comment: The error message I get now is : `TypeError: ShallowWrapper::dive() can not be called on Host Components`

Comment: That mean you should not use `dive`. Sorry but its very hard to follow your changes? So if you get the debug output as above and don't use `dive`, it still can't find `Header`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the dive() above and the test passed. But 1 doubt i have.Here I am writing the test as `comp.find(Header).prop("handleButtonClick")({ target: { value: "someValue" } });` . So, it is checking for an value right.But the function doesnot have any value passed. So my `({ target: { value: "someValue" } })` part should be `({ })` ? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell, you see this error because you are shallow rendering the `<SparkTheme />` Component. Shallow rendering does not render all the children in the node tree and therefore simulate does not find the Header Component.

Shallow rendering implicitly encourages you to test you components in isolation. Therefore, if you want to test it using shallow rendering, you should render the `<Header />` directly. It is difficult to give you more advice without seeing the code for your header component. How about adding some more code detail to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have tried doing comp.debug() and the output is pasted above in an edit. Can you please have a look at it and let me know what might be causing the issue?